How to Create a Barcode Scanner in Flutter That Displays a Sticky Square Around/On the Barcode
I'm developing a Flutter app and need to implement a QR scanner. I want the scanner to display a square around or on the detected QR code, which should stick to the QR code even as the camera moves.
Here’s an example of the sticky square on a QR code from Google Lens:

Has anyone done this before or have any suggestions on how to achieve it? Any examples or pointers to relevant packages would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Try to use mobile_scanner  package

It's called Overlay for QR Code and Barcode Scanner.
You can use packages for this or you can create your own overlay for this using CustomPainter.
I have used mobile_scanner to scan QR codes and I have created custom overlay for this:
Scanner Screen:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mobile_scanner/mobile_scanner.dart';
import 'package:resultscreen.dart';
import 'package:scanner_overlay.dart';

class Scanner extends StatefulWidget {
  const Scanner({super.key});

  @override
  State<Scanner> createState() => _ScannerState();
}

class _ScannerState extends State<Scanner> {
  final controller = MobileScannerController(
    formats: const [BarcodeFormat.qrCode],
    detectionSpeed: DetectionSpeed.noDuplicates,
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller.start();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          MobileScanner(
            controller: controller,
            onDetect: (capture) {
              Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500)).then(
                (value) {
                  final List<Barcode> barcodes = capture.barcodes;
                  for (final barcode in barcodes) {
                    debugPrint('QR Found! ${barcode.rawValue}');
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return ResultScreen(
                              resultText: '${barcode.rawValue}');
                        },
                      ),
                    ).then((value) => controller.start());
                  }
                  controller.stop();
                },
              );
            },
          ),
          QRScannerOverlay(
            callback: (value) {
              controller.stop();
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/resultscreen')
                  .then((value) => controller.start());
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> dispose() async {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

Overlay Screen:
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class QRScannerOverlay extends StatelessWidget {
  const QRScannerOverlay({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double scanArea = (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < 400 ||
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height < 400)
        ? 220.0
        : 330.0;
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: CustomPaint(
            foregroundPainter: BorderPainter(),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: scanArea + 25,
              height: scanArea + 25,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

// Creates the white borders
class BorderPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    const width = 4.0;
    const radius = 20.0;
    const tRadius = 3 * radius;
    final rect = Rect.fromLTWH(
      width,
      width,
      size.width - 2 * width,
      size.height - 2 * width,
    );
    final rrect = RRect.fromRectAndRadius(rect, const Radius.circular(radius));
    const clippingRect0 = Rect.fromLTWH(
      0,
      0,
      tRadius,
      tRadius,
    );
    final clippingRect1 = Rect.fromLTWH(
      size.width - tRadius,
      0,
      tRadius,
      tRadius,
    );
    final clippingRect2 = Rect.fromLTWH(
      0,
      size.height - tRadius,
      tRadius,
      tRadius,
    );
    final clippingRect3 = Rect.fromLTWH(
      size.width - tRadius,
      size.height - tRadius,
      tRadius,
      tRadius,
    );

    final path = Path()
      ..addRect(clippingRect0)
      ..addRect(clippingRect1)
      ..addRect(clippingRect2)
      ..addRect(clippingRect3);

    canvas.clipPath(path);
    canvas.drawRRect(
      rrect,
      Paint()
        ..color = Colors.white
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..strokeWidth = width,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}


You can also use qr_code_scanner for Overlay. you can find the code in example.
